# add string dynamically in objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to add string value dynamically from `result.text` and I wanted to display it in this way `[@"17052648287",@"17052607335"]` without losing the value. How can I do it?

```
NSMutableArray *strings = [@[@"17052648287",@"17052607335"] mutableCopy];
```

Add on coding

```
- (void)captureResult:(ZXCapture *)capture result:(ZXResult *)result{
    if (!result) return;

if(self.hasScannedResult == NO)
{
    //Scan Result, added into array
    NSString *scanPackage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result.text];

    scanLists = [NSMutableArray new];
    [scanLists addObject:scanPackage];

    NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *strings = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    strings = [@[result.text] mutableCopy];
    [preferences setObject:strings forKey:@"strings"];
    NSMutableArray *stringsArray = [preferences objectForKey:@"strings"];
    for (NSString *string in stringsArray) {
        NSLog(@"string: %@", string);
    }
```

Comment: you want to show the final output in this way `[@"17052648287",@"17052607335"]`

Comment: can you please explain more? structure of results.text etc. You just want all string in an array ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik yes

Comment: @Bhanupriya yes, I want to add in string in array. But the string I want it to be like this. For example the first time I get `result.text` is `[@"17052648287"]` den the second time I get result.text will be `[@"17052648287",@"17052607335"]`

Comment: First time,second time means?

Comment: @user3182143 because I scan something from QR Code, so this is the first  `result.text ["17052648287"]` I get. Den I want to add the second scan which is `result.text ["17052607335"]` and I wanted to put it in `["17052648287","17052607335"] `

Comment: @user3182143 so after that when I add the third one it will be automatically add on `["17052648287","17052607335", "third number"]`

Comment: Show your full coding

Answer (score 0):

Declare an results array:

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray new];
```

Write below code where you get your result.text:

```
NSString *scanPackage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", result.text]; // If this code is working for you
[array addObject: scanPackage];
NSString *combined = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","];
NSLog(@"combined: %@", combined);
```

Comment: I do not have any file, the result.text is taken from QR Code scan

Comment: yes got, but first can only "17052648287", second scan is "17052607335". Wanted to save it as ["17052648287","17052607335"]

Comment: I use the code u gave me it show "17052648287" for first scan, and when I scan "17052607335". the first "17052648287" replaced by the second scan

Comment: it can't, because array is mutable, its adding string objects to array.

Comment: If the path I replaced as result.text it will show me nil

Comment: If your result.text convert to string is working for you, check edited answer